# JSON.parse fails on array with object

Tags: javascript, json

In chrome, using this code

```
JSON.parse('[ "Rectangle", { width: 10 } ]')
```

throws me a

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token w
```

Internet Explorer 11(.0.9600) has a similar behaviour: `"Invalid character"`.

According to the definitions at http://json.org/, this syntax is clearly allowed and boils down to an array containing two elements: a string `"Rectangle"` and an object with one single property `width` and its value `10`

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Asad is right. FYI, the exact same error occurs in Chrome (and should occur in other browsers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JSON, object keys are strings, and therefore need to have quotes around them

```
JSON.parse('[ "Rectangle", { "width": 10 } ]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to convert it to proper JSON first:

```
let obj = ["Rectangle",{ width: 10 }];
obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
```